# Android Viewpager with nav Tabs exits the bottom screen

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

In my App i use the `ViewPager` with `Tabs` for the different tasks that the app can do.

It's work fine but i have a graphical issue with the Pager Container.

**PROBLEM:**
The device have a screen size and with `match_parent` i can cover the entire `width` and `height` of it.
But i don't know why, with the code below, the Pager Container has moved from the toolbar down and then out of the screen.

**ASK:**

How can i avoid this problem?
It is my fault or is it normal?

**CODE**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The result is this
[image]

And the `viewpager` go out of screen!

How i can avoid this?

I use this [Guide](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

**SOLUTION**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `app:layout_behavior` on your `ViewPager`.

The way it works is by off-setting your `ViewPager` the height of the toolbar down/out of the screen. When you scroll, and your `Toolbar` translates up/off the screen, it also slides your `ViewPager` up and in to the regular position. When you scroll and your `Toolbar` re-enters the view, it will translate your `ViewPager` down some to make room for the `Toolbar`.

Comment: The code for how the `app:layout_behavior` works can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java#L1132).

Comment: i try to remove it, but if i remove the `app:layout_behavior` all the fragments overlap to the bar.
My question is, how avoid this?
Adding a static margintop?
Or some best way?

Comment: When you scroll up/down it would hide/show the toolbar, putting the `ViewPager` in full view. If you do not need the hide/show scrolling effect from `CoordinatorLayout`, then you can just use something like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and have the `ViewPager` be under your `AppBarLayout`

Comment: Ok i understand, thanks for the explanation of the problem, now i post the solution to the question.
Can you check the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let us dissect the Views/ View Groups in the picture.

1) `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`
This is inherited from the `android.view.ViewGroup` having width and height as below

```
android:layout_width="match_parent" <= Full screen width in this case, rootView
android:layout_height="match_parent" <= Full screen height in this case, rootView
```

2) `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`
This is inherited from `LinearLayout` with Vertical Orientation having width and height as below

```
android:layout_width="match_parent" <= Full screen width
android:layout_height="wrap_content" <= Occupy screen height sufficient    
                                     enough to hold all the child Views.
```

3) AppBarLayout->child(0)->`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`
Inherited from `android.view.ViewGroup` having width and height as below

```
android:layout_width="match_parent" <= Full screen width
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" <= phone and OS version    
                                             dependent, say it is 48dip.
```

4) AppBarLayout->child(1)->`android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`
Inherited from `FrameLayout` with Horizontal Scrolling Capability

```
   android:layout_width="match_parent" <= Full screen width
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" <= Occupy screen height sufficient    
                                         to completely visible.
```

5) `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`
The main player of the view, inherited from the ViewGroup having width and height as below

```
android:layout_width="match_parent" <= Full screen width.
android:layout_height="match_parent" <= Full screen height.
```

**Important Information:**
The ViewGroup do not follow any policy like other inherited ViewGroups such as LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and so on where the children are adjusted based on the width and height of the other children availability. So ViewPager will have height and width same as the parent i.e. CoordinateLayout size but at offset from the top based on the LinearLayout height. **This is the reason you could see the ViewPager going out of the screen.**

There are various references at StackOverflow which tries to solve the problem but for your issue here is the simplest and logical resolution.

Solution:

STEP#1) Move the ViewPager into the AppBarLayout and set background with the required color.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
...
...
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" <= Replace this color of choice
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

STEP#2) OPTIONAL, Remove the scrolling property from the Toolbar otherwise one could see the blank space below the end of the ViewPager when scrolled up.

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Your utlimate file should look like

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope that helps...
Happy Coding... ;)

Comment: If you see my question i add the solution yesterday, Alex had post the problem and the solution first.
With a Relativelayout i solve it! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yup..I checked that. still I suggest to go for the CoordinatorLayout. Here is the quick reference for the CoordinatorLayout...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html. In simple terms you will miss the following advantages with RelativeLayout; a) Auto adjust of the FAB , up or down, when SnackBar is shown b) Expanding or Contracting toolbar to make room for the main content. i.e. to make app:layout_scrollFlags property to work c) Animations for the child views based on the coordinates.